# Subclass UITabBar to be presented with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitabbar

I have built an app based on a UITabBar. I want to have banner, for which I can present advertisement of my own. The banner will be a UIWebView which will simply load pictures from Google Drive.

My problem is that I want to connect the UIWebView to the UITabBar so that I won't have to draw this webView on every single view controller and so that the webView won't have to reload. I don't know how to do this and I do not even know if it is possible. Could someone give me any input on the matter?

Thanks for helping a fellow programmer out!

Comment: add your webView on UINavigationBar of main NvigationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to subclass UITabBar. In your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, create a webview and add it as a subview to your tab bar view controller's view.

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
[wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:wv];
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Just for clarification though. The above could should be implemented where the tabBarViewController is initialized, i.e. not necessarily in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.